# Method to send a weekly email to all users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, automation

I have currently set up this mailable.

Controller

```
class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendMail ()
    {
    $user = auth()->User::all();
    Mail::to($user)->send(new WeeklyUpdate($user));

    if(Mail::faillures())
    {
        return response()->Fail('Fail');
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->Success('Succses');
    }
}
```

Mail class

```
class WeeklyUpdate extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email.WeeklyUpdate');
}
```

How could I start with setting this up that, for instance, all users will get that weeklyUpdate email every sunday evening. I did do some research but only found partial explanations and since I am novice at Laravel, I would like some guidance as where to start with undertaking this.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch the job in the Laravel scheduler under `app\Http\Console\Kernel.php`

And specify the interval for the CRON job

Something like this should do

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    foreach (App\User::all() as $user) {
        $schedule->job(new SendWeeklyEmail($user))->weekly();
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a queued job setup like this

```php
class SendWeeklyEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Mail::to($this->user->email)->send(new App\Mail\WeeklyUpdate($this->user));
    }
}
```

[Learn More](https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling)

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for maybe sounding stupid, but how would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: Thankyou, makes sense. But if I already specify the time interval in the kernel, do I need to add the interval to the cronjob aswel?

Comment: No, the cron job has a timeout and retries, the interval is defined on the scheduler